# Automatic redirect to URL which can change in the meantime

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have a React app and we need to create a page which will inform the user that they will be redirected to a specific URL in 5 seconds. That's easy.

The tricky part is the possibility that the URL can change in the meantime. For example, the "basic" URL is `https://www.someurl.com`. When the page loads, I would set the timeout and that's simple. But at the same time we should send a certain request to the backend, and the response should contain some `id`. **IF** we receive the response in 5 seconds or less, we should redirect the user to `https://www.someurl.com?id=<id>`. Otherwise, we should just redirect them to that basic URL.

What would be the easiest way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You define a `ref` to keep track of the `id`. Using a `ref` will prevent a re-render when the `id` is stored.

Then, in a `useEffect`:

- Call a function that will trigger the request to the backend and update the `ref` once the request has finished.
- Set a timeout to run a `redirect` function that will check the value of the `ref` and redirect accordingly.

```js
// Define a ref to store the id fetched from backend.
const id = useRef(null);

const fetchId = useCallback(async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://example.com/request-to-backend');
  const id = getIdFromResponseBody(response);
  id.current = id;
}, []);

const redirect = useCallback(() => {
  if (id.current === null) {
    // Redirect to https://www.someurl.com
  } else {
    // Redirect to https://www.someurl.com?id=${id.current}
  }
}, [id]);

useEffect(() => {
  fetchId();
  setTimeout(redirect, 5000);
}, [fetchId, redirect]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine two events and execute them after the timer expires.

1: If you receive the response, save only the ID (window.responseId), and don't redirect.

2: When the 5s countdown is over, get the ID:

```
if (window.responseId) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something
}
```